# How can I download specific files recursive, while maintaining folder structure?

Tags: shell, files, rsync, download

So, I just downloaded a several folders using rsync, it went something like this:

```
rsync -rzP user@domain:/mnt/file_direction /mnt/Downloads/Files
```

This worked well for a massive download, however, now I need to just download certain files with a strucutre similar to these:

```
folder_a/folder_1/func/some_file.gz
folder_a/folder_2/func/some_file.gz
folder_b/folder_1/func/some_file.gz
folder_b/folder_2/func/some_file.gz
```

As you can see, these are files within concatenated folders. All files I need to download have the same format, so there should be no issues there.So, the gist of it is that I need to download just the "some_file.gz" while maintaining folder structure recursive.

Any and all help is much appreciated!

Comment: try this: rsync -rzP --include="*some_file.gz" --include="/*" --exclude="*" user@domain:/mnt/file_direction /mnt/Downloads/Files

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
rsync -rzP --include="*some_file.gz" --include="*/" --exclude="*" user@domain:/mnt/file_direction /mnt/Downloads/Files
```